# Azure function error : BinaryFormatter serialization and deserialization are disabled within this application

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, .net-6.0

i have existing azure function in .netCore 3.1, Trying to upgrade it to .net6.0. after upgrade getting error 'BinaryFormatter serialization and deserialization are disabled within this application. See https://aka.ms/binaryformatter for more information.'.
after below`<EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>true</EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization>` solution it works fine on local environment but once deployed on Azure function it gives same error again.
Can someone please help?

its very had to go through all code it has lot of custom nuget packages and tone of code in each package.

Answer (score 3):

csproj is not part of the deployed package.
in azure function use

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization", true);
```